# How to set Authorization for user in keycloak

Tags: javascript, jboss, authorization, wildfly, keycloak

I have 2 user:

1. user1
2. user2

and I have some page:

- localhost/index.php
- localhost/edit.php
- localhost/insert.php

I want to set user 1 can access to all page,user 2 can access to only page index.php. How to do it?
I was read [this doc](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/4.8/authorization_services/#_resource_server_enable_authorization), but i don't understand.

I am using keycloak 4.8.3.Final.

Comment: have you tried adding some roles to your users?

Comment: i was add offline_access and uma_authorization role for this user